# create sql trigger after insert

Tags: sql, database-trigger

i have two tables
 first table orders_details
with columns orders_id ,date, admin_id, comments

second table orders_tracking
with columns orders_id ,date, admin_id

in orders_details i have duplicates of rows

i want to create trigger that after row insert to orders_details
the c trigger 
check if order_id and admin_id already exist the date column update in orders_tracking
(take the date from orders_details) 
otherwise do insert to otherwise

**example** 
orders_details

```
id  order_id admin_id date(timestamp)   comments
1   1          2          111111111     test
2   1          2          111111511     test2
3   1          2          111111711     test3
4   1          3          111111161     test4
```

**example** 
orders_tracking

```
id order_id admin_id date(timestamp) 
1  1         2          111111111     
2  1         3          111111161
```

**insert**
now in orders_details have new insert

```
 order_id admin_id date(timestamp) comments
  5         2          111199111     test
```

**update**
now in orders_details have new insert

```
 order_id admin_id date(timestamp) comments
  1         2          111199111     test
```

**then** 
orders_tracking

```
id order_id admin_id date(timestamp) 
1  1         2          111199111     
2  1         3          111111161 
3  5         2          111199111
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and triggers are highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: What kind of "timestamp" is 111199111  supposed to be? A timestamp is something like `2020-01-06 17:18:19`

Comment: this timestemp just for example
if the row already exist the trigger just update the date (timestemp)
otherwise insert new row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

step-1 : create a table orders_details

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[orders_details](
            [ID] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
            [ORDER_ID] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
            [ADMIN_ID] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
            [DATE] [datetime] NULL,
            [COMMENTS] [varchar](50) NULL
```

) ON [PRIMARY]

Need to more details visit : [sql trigger after insert](http://www.esjay.org/2020/01/08/create-sql-trigger-after-insert/)

Comment: i have problem with DECLARE is not valid input at this position for this server version

Comment: Which version of MS SQL SERVER ?? this should use with MSSQL 2012

Comment: create MySQL 5.7 trigger after insert in this link (http://www.esjay.org/2020/01/10/create-mysql-trigger-after-insert/)